# Lambda functions with FXML in JavaFX8

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, scenebuilder

I'm working to an invader game in JavaFX with Scene Builder (I have to shoot planes whit a cannon) but I have got problems with lambda function.

I'm sure code is right because if I associate the code through Scene Builder's option (On action) it works, but, when I try to use lambda function, I can't change my scene. Where am I wrong?

```
public class SchermataGiocoController {

private Parent Menu, Avvio;
private TranslateTransition tt;
private Cannone cannone; //cannone = cannon
private Aereo aereo; //aereo = plane
private Proiettile proiettile; //proiettile = bullet
private RotateTransition rt;

@FXML
private Button down;

@FXML
private Circle circle;

@FXML
private Button su;

@FXML
private Button exit;

@FXML
private ImageView cannone_im;

@FXML
private AnchorPane SchermataGioco;

@FXML
private ImageView aereo_im;

@FXML
private Button menu;

@FXML
private Button home;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    assert exit != null : "fx:id=\"exit\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert cannone_im != null : "fx:id=\"cannone_im\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert su != null : "fx:id=\"su\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert SchermataGioco != null : "fx:id=\"SchermataGioco\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert aereo_im != null : "fx:id=\"aereo_im\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert menu != null : "fx:id=\"menu\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert down != null : "fx:id=\"down\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert home != null : "fx:id=\"home\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    cannone = new Cannone(141, 104, 14, 362);
    proiettile = new Proiettile(16, 16, 14, 362); 
    TranslateTransition();
}


 @FXML
 public void vaiMenu() {
    menu.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {                      
        try {                
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();                
            loader.setLocation(Game.class.getResource("/game/view/Menu.fxml"));
            Menu = (Parent) loader.load();
            menu.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
          ioe.getMessage();
        }            
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(Menu));
        stage.show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show how the working code looks like? Lambdas shouldn't make a difference at all.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you're actually trying to accomplish here?  I don't think your problem is related to Lambda expressions at all, but rather a misunderstanding of what Listeners do.

Comment: I would like to change scene using lambda function. I've edited the post adding other parts of the code. "menu" is a button, clicking on it, I should change my scene going in an other screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you associate `vaiMenu()` with the "On Action" in `SceneBuilder`, then (as it is expected), on e.g. when a click is performed on the `Button`, the `vaiMenu()` method will be executed, which will just do: assign a listener (through your lambda) for the action event of the `Button`, therefore it never will be executed, just added again-and-again.

If you want to assign the listener through `SceneBuilder` like:

```
<Button fx:id="menu" onAction="#vaiMenu" />
```

you cannot use lambdas (anonymous functions) as you need a named function to be referenced in your FXML file (in the `onAction` attribute).

If you insert your current lambda in e.g. the `initialize()` method of your controller, it will work without any problems, but in this case you should not define this attribute in your FXML file.