# Keyboard's arrow in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

It's me again! I have a cannon and for now I'm trying moving it with keyboard's arrows. I don't understand why code doesn't work? Where am I wrong?
Thank you!

```
public class SchermataGiocoController {

private Parent Menu, Avvio;
private TranslateTransition tt;
private Cannone cannone;
private Aereo aereo;
private Proiettile proiettile;
private RotateTransition rt;

@FXML
private Circle circle;

@FXML
private Button exit;

@FXML
private ImageView cannone_im;

@FXML
private ImageView carro;

@FXML
private AnchorPane SchermataGioco;

@FXML
private ImageView aereo_im;

@FXML
private Button menu;

@FXML
private Button home;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    assert exit != null : "fx:id=\"exit\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert cannone_im != null : "fx:id=\"cannone_im\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert carro != null : "fx:id=\"carro\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert SchermataGioco != null : "fx:id=\"SchermataGioco\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert aereo_im != null : "fx:id=\"aereo_im\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert up != null : "fx:id=\"up\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert menu != null : "fx:id=\"menu\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert down != null : "fx:id=\"down\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";
    assert home != null : "fx:id=\"home\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'SchermataGioco.fxml'.";

    //creazione di un oggetto Cannone
    cannone = new Cannone(129, 96, 0, 340); //Cannone = cannone
    //creazione di un oggetto Proiettile 
    proiettile = new Proiettile(16, 16, 0, 340); //proiettile = bullet
    //inizializzazione dei vari metodi
    TranslateTransition();
    moveUp();
    moveDown();
    goHome();       
}
    //Method to change scene and back to home
  public void goHome() {
    home.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {           
        try {               
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();               
            loader.setLocation(Game.class.getResource("/game/view/Avvio.fxml"));         

            Avvio = (Parent) loader.load();                
            home.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.getMessage();
        }           
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(Avvio));
        stage.show();
    });
}
  @FXML
public void moveUp() {       
    cannone_im.getScene().setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke) -> {
        if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.RIGHT)) {
            rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(100), cannone_im);
             if (cannone_im.getRotate() > -70) {
                rt.setAxis(Z_AXIS);                   
                rt.setByAngle(cannone_im.getRotate());                    
                rt.setToAngle(cannone_im.getRotate() - 5);
            } else {                    
                rt.setToAngle(-70);
            }
        }            
        rt.play();
    });
}
```

The error is that root cannot be null. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the update: your code has several problems.

**1)** *Key events are fired when the `Node` has focus*

Your `ImageView` will not have focus therefore the `KeyEvent` is never fired.

**Solution:** add the listener directly to your `Scene`.

This answer is a good reference: [How to write a KeyListener for JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962395/how-to-write-a-keylistener-for-javafx)

**2)** *You should not use `setOnKeyReleased`*

Especially in a game, it is really frustrating if the event just fired when you release the key.

**Solution:** Use `setOnKeyPressed` instead.

**3)** As you call `moveUp()` in initialize, it should not have the `@FXML` annotation

The `@FXML` annotation indicates that you want to use this function as a reference in the FXML file. But this method just creates the listener it is not the listener itself.

**Solution:** Remove the `@FXML` annotation from `moveUp()`

It is related to this question: [Lambda functions with FXML in JavaFX8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791698/lambda-function-in-javafx8/37791994#37791994)

**4)** You should ensure that the `sceneProperty` is not null before attaching the listener

**Solution:** Listen to the change of the `sceneProperty` of the `ImageView`.

*The final solution can be something like this:*

```
// The @FXML annotation is removed!
public void moveUp() {       
    cannone_im.sceneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Scene>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Scene> observable, Scene oldValue, Scene newValue) {

            if(newValue != null){
                cannone_im.getScene().setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke) -> {
                    if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.RIGHT)) {
                        rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(100), cannone_im);
                        if (cannone_im.getRotate() > -70) {
                            rt.setAxis(Z_AXIS);                    
                            rt.setByAngle(cannone_im.getRotate());
                             rt.setToAngle(cannone_im.getRotate() - 5);
                        } else {                    
                            rt.setToAngle(-70);
                        }
                    }
                    rt.play();
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've tried to run your code, but, if I write "cannone_im.getScene().setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke)-> ....." I get an error when I trie to change my Scene after setted my preferences about plane's speed ecc. Why?  Can you show me how to add a keyListener in my code? I've looked up the post you've linked, but I'm in tilt with the lambda function.

Comment: Update the question please with the current code and with the error you have.

Comment: Updated the answer for you.